# Is it possible to pass a field (not its value) as an argument in golang?

Tags: go

I have a program that is creating different leaderboards based on different fields in a slice of structs. This requires sorting the slice many times based on different fields where the only thing that is changing in the logic is the field being compared.

**Is there a way to encapsulate this repeated logic by passing a field (not its value) as an argument to a function?**

For clarification, here is rough approximation of the approach I am taking now:

```golang
type Person struct {
    Name  string
    Stat1 int
    Stat2 float64
}

person1 := Person{"Alice", 10, 2.0}
person2 := Person{"Bob", 12, 1.0}
person3 := Person{"Zach", 14, 0.1}

people := []Person{person1, person2, person3}

// Sorting based on one field
sort.Slice(people, func(i, j int) bool { 
    // Comparison logic that depends on comparing the Stat1 field
})
for i, p := range people {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(i+1) + " - " + p.Name + " with " + fmt.Sprint(people[i].Stat1))
}

// Sorting based on another field
sort.Slice(people, func(i, j int) bool { 
    // Comparison logic that depends on comparing the Stat2 field
    // but is otherwise identical to the comparison logic above
})
for i, p := range people {
    fmt.Println(fmt.Sprint(i+1) + " - " + p.Name + " with " + fmt.Sprintf("%.1f", people[i].Stat2))
}

// Many, many more of these...
```

Ideally I'd be able to do something like this (but think this may be impossible without generics):

```
func sortSliceByField(people []Person, fieldToSortOn PersonField) []Person {
    // Repeated sort logic on the field passed as an argument
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The repetitiveness of the code you displayed would not benefit from the solution you propose. However, you can make it a bit more structured by using something like this:

```
var SortOptions = map[string]func([]Person) func(int,int)bool {
  "stat1": func(people []Person) func(int,int) bool { 
     return func(i,j int) bool { return people[i].Stat1<people[j].Stat1 }
   },
  "stat2": func(people []Person) func(int,int) bool {
     return func(i,j int) bool { return people[i].Stat2<people[j].Stat2 }
   },
}
```

Then you can do:

```
sort.Slice(people,SortOptions["stat1"](people))
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I like a map here as a way of better organizing the sorting methods. I'll definitely consider it as an option. I do, however, think that a version of my solution would save repetition -- if the approach is possible in go. This is especially true because the comparison logic is identical (except for the field being compared) and more complex in the actual program. I'll update the question to try to make that more clear.